# #VALX breaking javascript

Tags: javascript, charts

I am trying to pass a x value from a chart to a javascript function using

```
Chart1.Series["Series3"].MapAreaAttributes = "onclick=\"javascript: showID(#VALX);\"";
```

The javascript function looks like this

```
function showID(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

(*This is just a tester function*)

When I send it a number value like `1234567` the function works perfectly fine but when I send it a value like `1234567A or 1234567B` I get the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Is there something wrong with my code or can I not send it with the letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using single quotes...

```
Chart1.Series["Series3"].MapAreaAttributes = "onclick=\"javascript: showID('#VALX');\"";
```

Comment: Yes I have 6 minutes until I can do so!